# git submodule: How do I keep a submodule current without commit to the superproject?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a superproject with a single submodule. That submodule is developed completely independent of the superproject, but that is not how my superproject is setup. Currently, when the origin of the submodule gets updated, the superproject only gets updated if someone (me) runs `git submodule update --recursive --remote` AND then commits that update to the superproject. That is stupid; I don't to track any versions or commit hashes of the submodule in my superproject. All I want is to have origin/master of submodule in my superproject, whatever origin/master happens to be. I want only to have to sync the submodule and NOT commit the submodule into my superproject.

For example, after doing a `git clone`, in order to get the submodule, I run `git submodule update --init --recursive` and get this:

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'scripts/token' (https://gitserver.company.com/token.git) registered for path 'scripts/token'
Submodule path 'scripts/token': checked out '93b6bee2031913f563f548883358a65a136bdd88'
```

But the commit hash 93b6bee2031913f563f548883358a65a136bdd88 is NOT origin/master of the token repo; that's 0f39201818985d21a1f2362ad5b519793bd4f2b6. In order to get that, I have run another `git submodule` command:

```
$ git submodule update --recursive --remote
Cloning into '/Users/me/superproject/scripts/token'...
Submodule path 'scripts/token': checked out '0f39201818985d21a1f2362ad5b519793bd4f2b6'
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   scripts/token (new commits)
```

No, I don't have "new commits" to superproject; I just synced a submodule. I want this to work like a dependency; I want `token>=0.0.1` (whatever is origin/master), but it seems like what I have is `token=explicit_commit_hash`. I don't want to support version numbers or commit hashes of submodule token in my superproject.

*UPDATE:* In other words, if `git status` says "up-to-date" with no local changes before running `git submodule update`, then after `git submodule update` updates the submodule, I STILL want `git status` to say "up-to-date" with no local changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The closest approximation I can think of is using an alias for your clone, a submodule update remote clone (surclone or whatever you wish to call it). Add the following to your `.gitconfig` file. Adding it via `git config --global alias.surclone` will not work since the shell will try to parse the arguments.

```
surclone = "!f() { git clone --recursive ${1} . && git submodule update --remote --recursive --init; }; f"
```

You can extend the command to automatically commit (`git commit --amend -a -m "Current master version of all submodules"`) and then force push it to the server (`git push -f`). This all requires that when adding the submodule, you also specify the branch it is to track, or add this later, e.g., `.gitmodules`

```
[submodule "SubmoduleA"]
    path = SubmoduleA
    url = git@github.com:some/repo.git
    branch = master
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is everything up to the `git commit`. I DON'T want to have the submodule update even be considered as modified code. If `git status` says "up-to-date", then after `git submodule update` updates the submodule, I STILL want `git status` to say "up-to-date" with no local changes.